# Golang добавление данных в slice struct-а

Tags: golang

Почему не получается добавить данные в slice structa-а?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"bytes"
)

type Rr struct {
    b []byte
}
func (r Rr) Show() []byte {
    return r.b
}

func (r Rr) Add(s string) {
    r.b = []byte(s)
}


func main() {
    var t Rr
    t.Add("asd")
    fmt.Println(t.Show()) // [] пустой срез почему?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если функция объявления для структуры (а не указателя)

```
func (r Rr) Add(s string) {
    r.b = []byte(s)
}
```

то r будет *копией* начальной структуры, т.е. изменения её полей не применяются на начальную структуру t (у которой метод был вызван). В частности Add работает с копией структуры, описывающей слайс, а не с той же структурой которая хранится в начальной t.b

slice - это структура из 3х элементов:

1. Указатель на область памяти
2. Текущая длина слайса
3. Максимальная ёмкость слайса

При добавлении байтов в слайс эти поля меняются, но все изменения остаются локальными внутри Add, т.к. она работает только с копией структуры, описывающей слайс.

Чтобы изменения применялись к r и в частности к слайсу b нужно объявлять функцию, работающую с указателем на Rr, т.е.

```
func (r *Rr) Add(s string) {
    r.b = []byte(s)
}
```

подробнее о слайсах: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Answer (score 0):

Используйте указатель

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"bytes"
)

type Rr struct {
    b []byte
}

func (r Rr) Show() []byte {
    return r.b
}

func (r *Rr) Add(s string) {
    r.b = []byte(s)
}

func main() {
    var t Rr
    t.Add("asd")
    fmt.Println(t.Show())         // [97 115 100]
    fmt.Println(string(t.Show())) // asd
}
```